# jQuery Mobile - refreshing a listview

Tags: jquery, listview, mobile

I have a dynamically added list on the "home" of my jQuery Mobile Page. Within a separate JS file, I have the following line to add the list:

```
$('#ListWrapper').append(html).trigger( "create" );
```

And all works fine. However, if the site is refreshed and the home page is not active, the list is added but without the jQuery Mobile styling. I tried adding this code but it didn't help:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if ($('.home').hasClass('ui-page-active')) {
        $("#ListWrapper ul").listview("refresh");
    }
});
```

Any help on how I can solve this problem? I'm happy to provide additional info as needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be calling the refresh method to early. Try calling the refresh in the pageshow event

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#HomePage').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
       $('#ListWrapper ul').listview('refresh');
     }) 
});
```